# How do I evaluate a property that I added to a jQuery Full Calendar event?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

In ASP.NET MVC I create a collection of CalendarEvent.  My C# CalendarEvent looks just like a jQuery Full Calendar event with the added property of EventType.  This way I can create a bunch of CalendarEvents and send them to a view and have the jQuery Full Calendar display them.

public class CalendarEvent
{

```
public int id { get; set; } //FC Title - Employee Name, Type of Day
public string title { get; set; } 
public bool allDay { get; set; }
public string start { get; set; } //required
public string end { get; set; } //required
public string url { get; set; } //optional
public string className { get; set; }
public bool editable { get; set; }
public bool startEditable { get; set; }
public bool durationEditable { get; set; }
public string color { get; set; }
public string backgroundColor { get; set; }
public string borderColor { get; set; }
public string textColor { get; set; }
public string EventType { get; set; }
```

}

In the full calendar eventRender, I try to change the background color of the event if the EventType == "ApprovedVacationDay".  When I debug the javascript, I notice the property EventType is not available.  When I view the objects come in via fiddler I do see the property EventType.  Is there a way to access and evaluate the EventType property and change the color of the event based on the value ?

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        dayClick: function (date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
            //alert(date.toString());

            //Add the date to the list of dates to be requested
            // if their is no event on date and it's a selectable date

            // Go to the server and see if the day is selectable (basic rules)
            // Not a holday, You dont have a day selected that day already



            $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
        },

        dayRender: function (daysOfWeek, cell) {
            $(cell).addClass('fc-state-highlight');
        },


        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            //right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            right: 'month,agendaWeek'

        },
        editable: false,
        events: function (start, end, callback)
        {
            var clockNo = $("#hiddenClockNo").val();
            // UNDONE This should not be hard set
            clockNo = 88888;
            var url = '@Url.Action(@"GetJSONVacationRequests?ClockNo=")';
            url = url + clockNo;
            url = decodeURIComponent(url);
            $.getJSON(url, function (locationsArray) {
                var result = $(locationsArray).map(function () {
                    return {
                        title: this.title,
                        start: this.start,
                        end: this.end,
                        allDay: this.editable
                    };
                }).toArray();
                callback(result);
            });
        },

        eventRender: function (event, element) {

            element.css('background-color', 'yellow');
            debugger;
            if(event.EventType =="ApprovedVacationDay")
            {
                element.css('background-color', 'green');
            }
        }


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
                    return {
                            title: this.title,
                            start: this.start,
                            end: this.end,
                            allDay: this.editable,

                        };
```

To:

```
                 return {
                            title: this.title,
                            start: this.start,
                            end: this.end,
                            allDay: this.editable,
                            EventType: this.EventType
                        };
```